# Exchanging numpy arrays between Python and Mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, data, interoperability, python

I've been using `np.savetxt(location, result, delimiter=',')` in Python followed by `Import[location,"CSV"]` in *Mathematica*. Some of my files are around 1GB, opening seems a bit slow, what else do people use for this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the binary format to speed up the process:

python side

```
import numpy as np
array = np.random.rand(100000000);
array.astype('float32').tofile('np.dat')
```

Mathematica side

```
data = 
   BinaryReadList["np.dat", "Real32"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.56679, Null} *)

data // Dimensions
(* {100000000} *)
```

Comment: Amazing, that cut my data loading time from 26.7544 seconds to 0.068415 seconds

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Glad it is helpful. I'm wondering how often do you use Mathematica in your work in ML? I'm considering switch my career to ML and am wondering whether my Mathematica skills are transferable.

Comment: I guess it depends on the kind of ML. I work on neural networks, and I use Mathematica for small scale experiments like [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1S0q8LuwgUCWT7n3Z2-YoM7LBL1yFCQt0NEtpUDrWX3I/edit), as well as checking math and making pretty plots. After sanity checks are done, rewrite everything in TensorFlow for large scale experiments.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks. I'm trying to build up my knowledge in neural network to be more competitive on the job market. As an insider of a leading AI research company, would you mind sharing a little bit information on what you are looking for from applicants? For example, if I'm targeting a company like OpenAI, do you think it would be beneficial for me to implement some deep learning applications (like [here](https://goo.gl/XAWOPU)), or it would be more useful to do some fundamental research such as how architectures and hyper-parameters influence the training and performance of neural net?

Comment: One way to get into OpenAI is to have state of the art implementations of some learning algorithms. Winning vizdoom contest, or imagenet challenge or some other hard contest would look pretty good.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov xslittlegrass I would also try HDF5 as the transfer format. It knows the type, so you don't have the remember that the file was 32-bit floating point.

Comment: I remember I tried a long time to make Mathematica read pickle file and failed, this looks like a really efficient substitution.

Comment: @Szabolcs so Mathematica HDF5 seems spotty, I get "Reading data of class H5T_VLEN is not currently supported"

Answer (score 16):

Here is a template to read a numpy binary ".npy" file created simply by

```
numpy.save(filename,array)
```

this file format has the array structure encoded as a python string that we need to parse..

> ```
> {'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (3, 4, 5), }
> ```

the byte order is also encoded so that this format is portable across hardware.

all of this code is parsing a small header and the actual data read is a single `BinaryReadList` so it should be very fast..

```
getnpy[file_] := 
  Module[{a, f = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True], version, 
    headerlen, header, dims, type, typ, byto},
    a = If[
     BinaryRead[f, "Byte"] == 147 &&         
      BinaryReadList[f, "Character8", 5] == Characters["NUMPY"] ,
     version = BinaryReadList[f, "Byte", 2];
     headerlen = BinaryRead[f, "Integer16", ByteOrdering -> -1];
     header = StringJoin@BinaryReadList[f, "Character8", headerlen];
     dims = StringCases[header,"'shape':" ~~ Whitespace ~~ "(" ~~ 
                 s : {NumberString, ",", Whitespace} .. ~~ ")" :> 
            ToExpression[
            "{" ~~
            If[StringTake[s, -1] == ",", StringDrop[s, -1], s] ~~ 
            "}"]][[1]];
     type = 
      StringCases[header, 
        "'descr':" ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
          Shortest["'" ~~ s : _ ... ~~ "'"] :> s][[1]];
     byto = 
      Switch[StringTake[type, 1], "<", -1, ">", 1, _, $ByteOrdering];
     If[MemberQ[{"<", ">","|","="}, StringTake[type, 1]], 
      type = StringDrop[type, 1]];
     typ = 
      Switch[ type ,
        "f8" , "Real64" ,
        "i8" , "Integer64" ,
          _  , Print["unknown type", header]; 0];
     If[typ != 0, 
      ArrayReshape[BinaryReadList[f, typ, ByteOrdering -> byto], 
       dims], 0 ], Print["not a npy"]; 0];
   Close[f]; a];

getnpy["test.npy"]
```

note I only put a couple of types you might encounter in the `Switch` . See the manual under `BinaryRead` if you need to add others.  Also I did not implement the 'fortran_order' key , just assume the default false.

Comment: is Numpy much faster than MMA ???